# Setting HP iLO Name

Tags: hp, ilo, blade-server

I need to change the iLO names that show up in "show server list" per client request.  The methodology I currently use is very slow (~25 minutes per chassis).

```
connect server N
set /system1 oemhp_server_name=ABC123
set /map1/dnsendpt1 Hostname=ABC123
{wait for prompt to return}
```

The above process is repeated for each blade in the chassis (16 per). Does anyone know of a faster methodology to do this exercise?

Comment: Rather than via the OA interface you can connect to each blade's own iLO interface and change them there, and in parallel if you script it that way, that said I've never found it that slow to do via the OA - is this on one chassis or more than one - what OA version?

Comment: We're having to do this for 76 chassis total.  Firmware Ver. : 4.50 Jul 24 2015, Hw Board Type : 2, Hw Version : B2   How would I do this directly on the iLO?

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of RIBCL scrpting language and perform those changes without connecting to each blade. From OA CLI interface run hponcfg tool.

To change **server names**:

```
OA> hponcfg bay_number << EOF
    <RIBCL VERSION="2.0">
        <LOGIN PASSWORD="user" USER_LOGIN="password">
        <SERVER_INFO MODE="write">
        <SERVER_NAME value="NewServerName"/>
        </SERVER_INFO>
        </LOGIN>
    </RIBCL>
    EOF
```

To change **iLO names** (iLO of the blade is reset automatically at the successful application of RBCL script):

```
OA> hponcfg bay_number <<EOF
<RIBCL VERSION="2.0">
<LOGIN USER_LOGIN="user" PASSWORD="password">
<RIB_INFO MODE="write">
<MOD_NETWORK_SETTINGS>
  <DNS_NAME value=" NewILOName" />
</MOD_NETWORK_SETTINGS>
</RIB_INFO>
</LOGIN>
</RIBCL>
EOF
```